# How to add number to beginning of each line?

Tags: shell, awk, command-line, sed

This is what I normally use to add numbers to the beginning of each line:

```
awk '{ print FNR " " $0 }' file
```

However, what I need to do is start the number at `1000001`.  Is there a way to start with a specific number like this instead of having to use line numbers?

Comment: Check out `man nl`. For example `nl -v 1000001 file`...

Comment: @twalberg: I think it should be `nl -ba ...`, since the OP wants to number **all** lines, which is not the default.

Comment: @user1934428 Fair enough. The main point, though, was to introduce a utility that the OP might not have been aware of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `1000001` to `FNR` (or `NR`):

```
awk '{ print (1000001 + FNR), $0 }' file
```

Answer (score 3):

there is a special command for this `nl`

```
nl -v1000001 file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ seq 5 | awk -v n=1000000 '{print ++n, $0}'
1000001 1
1000002 2
1000003 3
1000004 4
1000005 5

$ seq 5 | awk -v n=30 '{print ++n, $0}'
31 1
32 2
33 3
34 4
35 5
```